# How is the top Node of my Binary Search Tree updated when only making references to its copies

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree, shallow-copy

This question also applies to various linked lists methods as well. So, when I have a method:

```
    public void insert(String key) 
    {

        if(top == null) 
        {
            top = new Node(key);
            
        }else {
            Node newNode = new Node(key);
            Node rover = top;
            Node prev = top;
            boolean wentLeft = true;

            while(rover != null) 
            {
                if (rover.getName().compareTo(key) < 0)
                {
                    prev = rover;
                    rover = rover.getRight();
                    wentLeft = false;
                }else {
                    wentLeft = true;
                    prev = rover;
                    rover = rover.getLeft();
                }
            
            }
                
            if(wentLeft == true) 
            {
                prev.setLeft(newNode);
            }else {
                prev.setRight(newNode);
            }
        }
        nElems++;
        
    }
```

How is the top of the Binary Search Tree and its children updated despite not being directly set anywhere in the method?

I know this likely has something to do with shallow copying and that like rover/prev are still referencing top in memory but I still don't really get it.

Even though I feel like I understand Linked Lists and Binary Search Trees on a conceptual level I don't feel comfortable moving forward with them without understanding this.

Comment: What do you think the code in your question does?

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the code you don't understand. What is unclear for you?

Comment: @PM77-1 I understand that it adds a new Node of whatever key to tree based on its value regarding if its less or more than top then the left/right child of top etc I don't understand that how when top is never reset or used when I go back after Inserting say like "Apple" to a tree whose top is "Banana" how it actually got set to the left of it without actually saying top.setLeft("apple") or  prev.setLeft("apple") then top.setLeft(prev). I am not asking what the code does its more why and how it works.

Comment: For clarification: prev = top does NOT create a shallow copy. I think this is the point you're misunderstanding. After prev = top, top.setLeft(x) and prev.setLeft(x) do the exact same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no copies being made. When you assign prev = top, that only creates another reference to the same object as top, not a copy.

The code works because nodes are inserted one by one.
When prev.setLeft/setRight is called, prev is already in the tree because it was inserted before. So prev is already in the tree, i. e. the parent of prev is top, or the parent of the parent of prev, you get the idea. Thus, when new_node becomes child of prev, it becomes part of the tree.

This is what makes linked lists and trees so useful. When you insert an element, you only have to make one connection.

Comment: So because I'm referencing top that allows me to traverse it with prev or rover without changing top and then add to it based on where those Nodes are pointing in the list?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Top remains "pointing" at the same element while the code traverses the tree using prev and rover. Low-level languages like C are more clear about the concept of pointers, but more verbose, too. In Java, when you have an Object (usually types beginning in a capital letter like String or Node), a = b only creates another pointer to b, pointing to the same object. To create another object, you'd have to actively create a copy. This is different for primitive types such as int and float.